# Oracle Trigger Error - ORA-04080: trigger 'TRIG' does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I wrote a database trigger that will not allow any changes to the salary value of employees who have less than 3 years of experience.

emp(eno(P.K.),name,salary,exp)

I have encountered the following error that I am unable to resolve.

ORA-04080: trigger 'TRIG' does not exist

Errors: TRIGGER TRIG
Line/Col: 2/5 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line/Col: 2/9 PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXP'

```
DROP TABLE EMP;
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
    ENO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(15),
    salary NUMBER,
    exp NUMBER 
);

insert into EMP Values (1,'AMAN',15000,5);
insert into EMP Values (2,'BHAMAN',54000,0);
insert into EMP Values (3,'CHAMAN',68000,3);
insert into EMP Values (4,'DAMAN',5000,9);
insert into EMP Values (5,'KHAMAN',95000,6);

DROP trigger trig;
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger trig
BEFORE UPDATE of salary ON EMP
begin
    if (exp<3) then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20011,'CHANGES IN SALARY NOT ALLOW');  
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Please never ask for help on SO saying "i got an error" or "my code is wrong" without saying exactly *what the error message is* or *exactly why you think/are told the code is wrong* - we always need more details than "this broke, not telling why, plz fix"

Comment: regardless of your unknown error, you have a glaring design flaw.  If column EXP represents 'experience'  (years of experience?) then you would need to be constantly updating it.  What you _should_ do is store the _date_ that is considered the start of their 'experience'.  I'd assume it would the the date they were hired.  By storing the _date_ you can always calculate 'experience' when needed by simply subtracting the stored date from sysdate.

Comment: The cause of this error `Error is ORA-04080: trigger 'TRIG' does not exist` is that if we drop a table we drop all the objects owned by that table, like triggers. You don't need that statement.

Comment: The other error you get because `exp()` is [an Oracle built-in function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/EXP.html#GUID-414FB4AE-03B5-41AD-AE33-E3755EFED0A0) and is confusing the compiler. You need to prefix the column name with the `:new` trigger namespace. Or as @EdStevens suggests store the HIREDATE instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a row-level trigger and not a table-level trigger.

You need to add `FOR EACH ROW` and change `exp` to `:old.exp` (or `:new.exp`, as appropriate):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trig
BEFORE UPDATE OF SALARY ON EMP
FOR EACH ROW
begin
    if :old.exp < 3 then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20011,'CHANGES IN SALARY NOT ALLOW');  
    end if;
end;
/
```

Then:

```sql
UPDATE EMP
SET salary = 200
WHERE eno = 3;
```

Works, but:

```sql
UPDATE EMP
SET salary = 200
WHERE eno = 2;
```

Raises the exception:

> ```
> ORA-20011: CHANGES IN SALARY NOT ALLOW
> ORA-06512: at &quot;FIDDLE_OVDSPTLUYURCFSYNXGOO.TRIG&quot;, line 3
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_OVDSPTLUYURCFSYNXGOO.TRIG'
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c3e57f6711336eaadf754ab52a17fbc)*

However, a better data model would be to store the date the employee was hired and then compare the current date to the hire date plus 3 years and that way your `exp` column does not become outdated as time progresses.